# Determining the CPU architecture of a static library (LIB) on Windows

Tags: windows, 64-bit, static-libraries, cpu-architecture, libpng

I just built libpng on a 64-bit Windows machine using VS2008. It produces a `libpng.lib` file inside the \projects\visualc71\Win32_Lib_Release directory (Configuration used being "LIB Release").

I used `dumpbin` to inspect this LIB file:

```
C:\Temp\libpng-1.4.3>dumpbin projects\visualc71\Win32_LIB_Release\libpng.lib
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 9.00.30729.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file projects\visualc71\Win32_LIB_Release\libpng.lib

File Type: LIBRARY

  Summary

         8E4 .debug$S
         DF2 .drectve
        2BCD .rdata
       21165 .text

C:\Temp\libpng-1.4.3>
```

It does not however show the architecture of the LIB file. How do I find if a given LIB file is built for 32-bit or 64-bit architecture?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Use dumpbin /headers

The machine type is almost the first line you'll get.

It will be 14c for x86 and 8664 for x64

> n:>dumpbin lib642.lib /headers
>
> Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version
>   10.00.30319.01 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Dump of file lib642.lib
>
> File Type: LIBRARY
>
> FILE HEADER VALUES
>               8664 machine (x64

Or

> n:>dumpbin Lib32.lib /headers
>
> Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version
>   10.00.30319.01 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Dump of file Lib32.lib
>
> File Type: LIBRARY
>
> FILE HEADER VALUES
>                14C machine (x86)

Comment: This property extension for Windows Explorer shows architecture information without using a tool: http://sanje2v.wordpress.com/2013/12/10/writing-property-handler-for-windows-explorermanta-property-extension/

Comment: The `dumpbin` command is available in a [Visual Studio Command Prompt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229859)