# VS2013 Error: LNK2019 When trying to build ZeroMQ server

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, zeromq

I'm trying to build this simple ZeroMQ server in C++ on Visual Studio 2013.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "zmq.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // Prepare context and socket
    zmq::context_t ctx(1);
    zmq::socket_t sckt(ctx, ZMQ_REP);
    sckt.bind("tcp://*:5555");

    while (true) {
        zmq::message_t request;

        // Wait for next request from client
        sckt.recv(&request);
        std::cout << "Received Hello" << endl;
        Sleep(1);

        // Send reply back to client
        zmq::message_t reply(5);
        memcpy((void*)reply.data(), "World", 5);
        sckt.send(reply);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

However, I'm getting error LNK2019 when I try to build the VS project. Below is the compiler output:

```
1>ZeroMQServer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__zmq_errno referenced in function "public: __thiscall zmq::error_t::error_t(void)" (??0error_t@zmq@@QAE@XZ)
1>ZeroMQServer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__zmq_strerror referenced in function "public: virtual char const * __thiscall zmq::error_t::what(void)const " (?what@error_t@zmq@@UBEPBDXZ)
1>ZeroMQServer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__zmq_ctx_new referenced in function "public: __thiscall zmq::context_t::context_t(int,int)" (??0context_t@zmq@@QAE@HH@Z)
1>ZeroMQServer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__zmq_ctx_set referenced in function "public: __thiscall zmq::context_t::context_t(int,int)" (??0context_t@zmq@@QAE@HH@Z)
1>ZeroMQServer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__zmq_ctx_destroy referenced in function "public: void __thiscall zmq::context_t::close(void)" (?close@context_t@zmq@@QAEXXZ)
1>ZeroMQServer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__zmq_msg_init referenced in function "public: __thiscall zmq::message_t::message_t(void)" (??0message_t@zmq@@QAE@XZ)
1>ZeroMQServer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__zmq_msg_init_size referenced in function "public: __thiscall zmq::message_t::message_t(unsigned int)" (??0message_t@zmq@@QAE@I@Z)
1>ZeroMQServer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__zmq_msg_send referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall zmq::socket_t::send(class zmq::message_t &,int)" (?send@socket_t@zmq@@QAE_NAAVmessage_t@2@H@Z)
1>ZeroMQServer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__zmq_msg_recv referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall zmq::socket_t::recv(class zmq::message_t *,int)" (?recv@socket_t@zmq@@QAE_NPAVmessage_t@2@H@Z)
1>ZeroMQServer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__zmq_msg_close referenced in function "public: __thiscall zmq::message_t::~message_t(void)" (??1message_t@zmq@@QAE@XZ)
1>ZeroMQServer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__zmq_msg_data referenced in function "public: void * __thiscall zmq::message_t::data(void)" (?data@message_t@zmq@@QAEPAXXZ)
1>ZeroMQServer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__zmq_socket referenced in function "public: __thiscall zmq::socket_t::socket_t(class zmq::context_t &,int)" (??0socket_t@zmq@@QAE@AAVcontext_t@1@H@Z)
1>ZeroMQServer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__zmq_close referenced in function "public: void __thiscall zmq::socket_t::close(void)" (?close@socket_t@zmq@@QAEXXZ)
1>ZeroMQServer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__zmq_bind referenced in function "public: void __thiscall zmq::socket_t::bind(char const *)" (?bind@socket_t@zmq@@QAEXPBD@Z)
1>D:\[ Source Code ]\C++\ZeroMQServer\Debug\ZeroMQServer.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 14 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I have installed the [ZeroMQ binary v4.0.4](http://miru.hk/archive/ZeroMQ-4.0.4~miru1.0-x64.exe) and updated the VS project properties to point to ZeroMQ's include and lib paths. Specifically, this is what I have updated in the project properties (I suspect some of these settings may be redundant):

1. Configuration Properties > VC++ Directories > Include Directories: Added '$(ZEROMQ_HOME)\include'
2. Configuration Properties > VC++ Directories > Library Directories: Added '$(ZEROMQ_HOME)\lib'
3. Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories: Added '$(ZEROMQ_HOME)\include'
4. Configuration Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies: Added 'libzmq-v120-mt-4_0_4.lib;libzmq-v120-mt-gd-4_0_4.lib'

I'm on Win 7, 64-bit Edition.
Please help me resolve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the library names on [zeromq.org](http://zeromq.org/distro:microsoft-windows), you are trying to link the same library twice: first with the release version, and then with the debug versions.

Remove `libzmq-v120-mt-gd-4_0_4.lib` from your Release configuration, and remove `libzmq-v120-mt-4_0_4.lib` from your Debug configuration.

[edit]

Your application probably is 32bit, and the library you are trying to link with is 64bit. (You can use dumpbin to determine what architecture a .lib file is for, [see this answer for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3336867/3931225). Please use the 32bit library, or change your application to 64bit.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the problem persists. Are there are any additional dependencies of the ZeroMQ library that I'm not aware of?

Comment: No other dependencies that i can see. The first unresolved external symbol `zmq_errno` should be present in `libzmq` itself: http://api.zeromq.org/4-0:zmq-errno. Did you do a rebuild? And you don't happen to have crazy characters in any of your pathname's do you?

Comment: Yes, I did a rebuild. And no, I don't have any crazy characters in the pathname. :)

Comment: Ah, i see now. Your application probably is 32bit, and the library you are trying to link with is 64bit. (You can use dumpbin to determine what architecture a .lib file is for, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322630/determining-the-cpu-architecture-of-a-static-library-lib-on-windows). Please use the 32bit library, or change your application to 64bit.

Comment: Yup, That was it. Checked with _dumpbin_ and as you suspected, it is a 64 bit library. Thanks for helping me resolve this. Cheers!

Comment: thanks for this. Had the same problem, which was having the 0MQ 64bit library and my C++ project targeting 32bit platforms.

Comment: @KompjoeFriek  How did you go from the error messages posted above to your  conclusion _...you are trying to link the same library twice..._ ??  That does not match what I see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2019?view=msvc-160)

Comment: I looked at the configuration (item 4) and noticed a mistake. Error was caused by a different configuration error (32bit application, 64bit library). I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

I had to define ZMQ_STATIC since I wanted to link zmq statically.
By default all these functions  defined as

elif defined DLL_EXPORT

## define ZMQ_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same errors. But for me they were produced by a wrong set calling convention.
(Just wanted to mention it here because it cost me more than a hour to track it.)