# Compilation project with Cmake . I'm getting an error

Tags: opencv, cmake

I'm trying to compile a project with CMake. I'm getting an error:

Found OpenCV Windows Pack but it has not binaries compatible with your
  configuration.

You should manually point CMake variable OpenCV_DIR to your build of OpenCV
  library.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:9 (FIND_PACKAGE)

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (FIND_PACKAGE):
  Found package configuration file:

```
C:/Users/Ghenja/AppData/Local/opencv/build/OpenCVConfig.cmake
```

but it set OpenCV_FOUND to FALSE so package "OpenCV" is considered to be
  NOT FOUND.

I don't understand what is happening. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: `set(OpenCV_FOUND 1)` before `find_package`

Comment: It doesn't work. The problem didn't escape.

Answer (score 0):

Clean your project and remove CMakeCache.txt. OpenCV_FOUND is probably cached now.

If that doesn't work, then run your cmake command with additional flags just to be sure:

```
cmake -DOpenCV_FOUND:BOOL=ON -DOpenCV_DIR=/path/to/your/OpenCV
```

Comment: After doing  suggested command I'm getting the same error as in my post.  Removing CMakeCache.txt  didn't help me too.  I use Windows 64-bit if it is important.

Comment: Have you verified that the libraries you have in the directory are built for 64-bit not 32-bit?

Comment: I don't know how to have verified it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322630/determining-the-cpu-architecture-of-a-static-library-lib-on-windows